# Finding if a number falls within a certain range python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to categorize numbers into "bins" so if a bin is all numbers in the range 0 to 20, then 19 falls into that bin.

I'm trying to do this without using a bunch of if-then states like so:

```
if x < 0.5:
    return "bin1"
elif x < 0.8:
    return "bin2"
...
```

Numpy has a numpy.linspace method that generates a numpy array with evenly spaced bins. However, I still don't see how to do this bin categorization efficiently without taking the results of the array and putting them in "if" statements. Thanks.

Comment: Are your bins contiguous and do they all have the same width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import bisect

bins = range(0, 100, 15)

print bisect.bisect_left(bins, 35)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.searchsorted`:

```
>>> import numpy as np    

>>> bins = np.array([0, 10, 100, 1000])
>>> numbers = np.array([800, 8, 80])
>>> print bins.searchsorted(numbers)
[3, 1, 2]
```